# How to extract a local variable to a class variable in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

I want be able to transform a local variable declared in a method into a class variable. Please see the example below.

```java
// This is my class now
public class FOO {
    public getX() {
        String X = "test"
        return X;
    }
}
```

With a keyboard shortcut, the variable X should be transformed into a class variable. The end result should look like this:

```java
// This is what my class should look like afterwards
public class FOO {
    String X = "test"
    public getX() {
        return X;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do this in IntelliJ?

Comment: Highlight it, `CTRL ALT F`

Comment: Where did you look for answers (IntelliJ help, IntelliJ manual) and why didn't the solutions shown there help you? [ask]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Highlight `X` and <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

Replace F with the following letters for other types of extraction

- F = field
- P = parameter
- V = variable
- C = constant (static field)
- M = method

Also accessible via

Right click > Refactor > Extract

Comment: This works, though it's annoying that it renames my variable

Answer (score 0):

`Ctrl + Alt + F` is the refactoring algorithm you're looking for.
Refactor -> Extract -> Field

You'll want to use "Initialize in field declaration" setting of this refactoring algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

On Mac the shortcut to do this is <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>.